# NSUserDefaults Causing Crash

Tags: iphone, sdk, nsuserdefaults

Long story, short, I am currently using this code in my viewDidLoad to restore any values that were saved (using NSUserDefaults) and to also check if this is the first time running the app. Everything works fine until I test the NSUserDefaults by restarting the phone, or deleting the app from my multitasking. Basically the app opens frozen, crashed,  can't do anything. I have a feeling it has something to do with recalling the values that might not be there.

```
NSDictionary *defaultsDict =
[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], @"FirstLaunch", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:defaultsDict];

NSUserDefaults *sharedDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([sharedDefaults boolForKey:@"FirstLaunch"]) {

    NSLog(@"first launch");

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.view cache:YES];
    [nameView removeFromSuperview];
    [amountView removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:firstView];
    [initialText becomeFirstResponder];

    [sharedDefaults setBool:NO forKey:@"FirstLaunch"];
    [sharedDefaults synchronize];
}

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSObject * object = [defaults objectForKey:@"budgetLabel"];
if(object != nil){

    NSString *budgetSaved = [defaults objectForKey:@"budgetLabel"];
    NSArray *namesSaved = [defaults objectForKey:@"nameArray"];
    NSArray *pricesSaved = [defaults objectForKey:@"priceArray"];

    budgetLabel.text = budgetSaved;
    [nameArray addObjectsFromArray:namesSaved];
    [priceArray addObjectsFromArray:pricesSaved];
} else {

}
```

Remember, any help is appreciated!

**EDIT**

This is the code I use to store the data:

```
- (void)saveData {
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:budgetLabel.text forKey:@"budgetLabel"];
[defaults setObject:nameArray forKey:@"nameArray"];
[defaults setObject:priceArray forKey:@"priceArray"];
[defaults synchronize];
}
```

Comment: Show *where* you are putting this code. Also, which line is the crash on, and what does the crash log say?

Comment: I am putting the code first thing in the viewDidLoad. There is no crash log because when I restart the phone or delete the app from multitasking, the debugger crashes, cause it lost connection with the app.

Comment: Then don't do that. Stop running in Xcode. Now on the phone delete the app. Now run from Xcode again. What happens?

Comment: When I do it the way you said, the app works fine! Let me try without connecting to computer...

Comment: Okay, great! App is responsive. It restores the value budgetLabel.text but does not restore the value of the arrays, ideas?

Comment: That might be related to how you are storing the data.  Could you show us that part too?

Comment: Just updated my post, now has that code.

Comment: Where is your error log?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *namesSaved = [defaults objectForKey:@"nameArray"];
```

Using this you are getting non mutable array and then

```
[nameArray addObjectsFromArray:namesSaved];
```

You are adding it in mutableArray.

Thats why its creating crash.

Comment: Okay, I changed it to NSMutableArray *namesSaved = [defaults objectForKey:@"nameArray"]; But it still does not restore the values.

Comment: NSMutableArray *namesSaved=[NSMutableArray new];

Comment: namesSaved = [defaults objectForKey:@"nameArray"];

Comment: Same problem, does not restore the array in the UITableView.

Comment: so let me know how are you creating nameArray??/

Comment: Actually, I posted it in my code, I thought you were taking about the actual array.

Comment: mean how you are declaring nameArray? like NSArray or NSMutableArray

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

I have solved my problem with the following code:

```
nameArray = [[defaults mutableArrayValueForKey:@"nameArray1"] mutableCopy];
priceArray = [[defaults mutableArrayValueForKey:@"priceArray1"] mutableCopy];
```

Thanks for the help everyone!